# Condition Flow's return type on the input parameter type

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Is there a way to to properly condition the return type on the input parameter in flow?

The following function is a simple optional recursion that shouldn't be too hard for flow to parse but I can't get it to work:

```
type XYpos = {| x: number, y: number |}
type RelativeCoordinates = {...XYpos} | Array<{...XYpos}>; // Use spread to loose the exact type
type MappedCoordInput = XYpos | Array<XYpos>;
function getMappedCoords(position: RelativeCoordinates, 
                         width: number, 
                         height: number): MappedCoordInput {
  if (position instanceof Array) {
    return position.map(p => getMappedCoords(p, width, height));
  }

  return {
    x: position.x * width,
    y: position.y * height,
  };
}
```

This gives the error in Flow ([here](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAGgmmA9gZygXigbwD5QB4BcUAdgK4C2ARhAE4A0UIRZVtU2AvgFCiRQBKEADYBDYAEsAbhADCiRDQAm44mIioMmAHQ74SZB3ZQAgjRoiQAHm26EKDgD4A3FAD0rqAFVk0ZGBoQIopQwIhQQvI+IQAW0BB4IgDGwCHgEDxpUACyImCQinIKigCSxGCkKRh6KEam5lbVyM5cAGakxMniiMRQAOYQwDl5EAXySsgAFPriEt1EgqIS0oVKKmrIDADu4orA0cwU1PRQseK90cAHrDQAlERD+SslZRVYXFBQ4i1QUygzXT0VMhgCIOhBEN86hYbm8Ph8AsBSDQetNZsQtORclN0A4+gMHiMnpMwFsdnsGKdzsAbjcnO8oNx6QikT1MPSPoQoKiAVo8FAAFRQba7aJ0dmMIjc7paEACk4QM4XMUfDh07hAA) is the "Flow try"):

```
6:     return position.map(p => getMappedCoords(p, width, height));
              ^ array type. Has some incompatible type argument with
3: type MappedCoordInput = XYpos | Array<XYpos>;
                                   ^ array type
    Type argument `T` is incompatible:
        6:     return position.map(p => getMappedCoords(p, width, height));
                                        ^ array type. Inexact type is incompatible with exact type
        3: type MappedCoordInput = XYpos | Array<XYpos>;
                                                 ^ object type
```

I've also played around with generics but that doesn't seem to help:

```
type XYpos = {| x: number, y: number |}
type CoordInput = XYpos | Array<XYpos>;
function getMappedCoords<P: CoordInput>(position: P, 
                         width: number, 
                          height: number): CoordInput {
  if (position instanceof Array) {
    return position.map(p => getMappedCoords(p, width, height));
  }

  return {
    x: position.x * width,
    y: position.y * height,
  };
}
```

### Update

Casting resolves the immediate error but doesn't solve have the question about the return type being resolved via an input parameter:

```
type XYpos = {| x: number, y: number |}
type RelativeCoordinates = {...XYpos} | Array<{...XYpos}>;
type MappedCoordinates = XYpos | Array<XYpos>;
function getMappedCoords(
  position: RelativeCoordinates,
  width: number,
  height: number,
): MappedCoordinates {
  if (position instanceof Array) {
    const ret = position.map(p => getMappedCoords(p, width, height));
    return ((ret: any): Array<XYpos>);
  }

  const truePos: XYpos = {
    x: position.x * width,
    y: position.y * height,
  };
  return truePos;
}

const pos: XYpos = getMappedCoords({ x: 1, y: 1}, 2, 2);
const arrayXpos: Array<XYpos> = getMappedCoords([{x: 1, y: 1}], 2, 2);
```

The Flow testing platform still [complains](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQAXAngBwKagBoE11YBnUAXlAG8AfUADwC5QA7AVwFsAjTAJwBpRUjVpx6gqAXxQZsAJUzQAhsgCWAN0wBhWLG4ATZUyWYS5CgDoL+QkXFjQAQW7cFqADznLBYuIB8AbiksUABZBXQsXS0dfUNkYzJcLxIaR2c3K2J-REgWJgBjFVgmUABzTGRQ8MxI7T0iAApEUFBrZUKmRjlFFXUovQMjIl4m0HhlXWQACyF2Lj4RycxlEsnkGZF5gEpGSoi+mMHKEeVIUHrW9tADImQFfMxYU9SXTaPm5ryim9BucoSL5RFMxsMLnMg+UrlXbVfYNdD8MYTSb8RbLVabTYBd4-cosbjFer1X5rUB3VDbBxOFyuDJEHyYkaSEafJjfZDcFiYAAKxEYtISFBGzQYLWIbUBTDMtFAACpRuMpsNsYJRURxUDULLQKiVsglaBxFiccg8cV2ZyeUQAkyWd9rHykgkyhUwntaroGhQ6IwAIz8FU+8T8ABMIYZtuQpKpqBw9spaRpSQh5Gd0Jq0QaAG0KCK-QJfeIALohsN+IA):

```
22: const pos: XYpos = getMappedCoords({ x: 1, y: 1}, 2, 2);
                       ^ array type. Inexact type is incompatible with exact type
22: const pos: XYpos = getMappedCoords({ x: 1, y: 1}, 2, 2);
               ^ object type
23: const arrayXpos: Array<XYpos> = getMappedCoords([{x: 1, y: 1}], 2, 2);
                                    ^ object type. This type is incompatible with
23: const arrayXpos: Array<XYpos> = getMappedCoords([{x: 1, y: 1}], 2, 2);
                     ^ array type
```

Comment: Why not simply two different functions?!

Comment: @JonasW. Yeah - that's what I would call the cheap fall back solution :-D

Comment: The sense of typing is to make your code failsafe. These multitypes male it impossible to find errors, so its quite senseless...

Comment: @JonasW. I can agree that there are benefits having that coding style, the question is though not about coding styles. There are plenty of libraries out there that have the similar issues and unless we want to rewrite all of them it would be nice if Flow allowed for more flexibility so that these can be extended with proper Flow typings.

Comment: why typing them then at all?

Comment: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/casting/

Comment: @JonasW. I've updated the example with casting - ugly but works with the previous error. I still don't get the intention where the input relates to the output. This type of behavior doesn't seem that strange and it seems that [generics](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/) intend to solve this issue. I've looked at the [utility types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/) but I don't see anyone really applicable to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Because, as defined, when your function accepts an Array for position, the type of *each element in that array* after mapping is `MappedCoordInput`. That is saying that position.map can be an array of arrays, which is incompatible with the return type of the function -- which is just an array of objects, not an array of array of objects.

As it is currently coded, `[[[{x: 1, y: 1}]]]` is a valid input. However, it will not run `Array<XYPos>`. It will return `Array<Array<Array<XYPos>>>`, which does not match the return type of `MappedCoordInput`.

Comment: The input should not allow that though and the question is if it is possible to condition based on the input the return type

Comment: Fair enough that the input doesn't allow it, but despite the input's definition, it is saying that it can return it as an output.